# Installing Unsigned Network Protocol Driver Windows 2012R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-protocols

I'm trying to install an unsigned Network protocol driver on a 2012 R2 Windows server installation however the installation just fails the same way unsigned device driver fails.

I've already unlock windows via the initial boot to allow the installation of unsigned device drivers, however this does not seem to allow me to install the unsigned network protocol drivers

Any help appreciated, Thanks

**Edit**

For anyone interested, the driver in question is a SquareD / SYENET network driver protocol.

**Edit**
When prompted to choose the file where the protocol network driver is, all i get is a Unable to find any drivers for this device screen

[image]

Comment: `I'm trying to install an unsigned Network protocol driver on a 2012 R2 Windows server` - Out of curiosity, what is this driver exactly?

Comment: a syenet protocol driver @joeqwerty

Comment: Any error messages that could provide a hint?